# DNN 2sxc blog sharing parent page's meta title and description

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, blogs, facebook-sharer, 2sxc

We are having a problem with Facebook share not showing the correct picture, meta title and description.

Ex. something.com/blog/post/examplePostName/ is showing meta title and description of the something.com/blog/ parent page.
When we view the source for each of these two pages everything looks correct meta, og:graph, twitter card, but the sharer on the page (AddThis) is still not pulling the right stuff.

When we tried it out on the Facebook debugger page it is showing the correct meta, but sharing from the page (by clicking on AddThis) is still pulling the parent page meta.

Did anyone have this issue?

Could it be that we missed something in the blog app settings?

Comment: I suspect it'd be a lot easier to debug this if you shared some code :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. :) I was not sure what to share, and what I could. Had to ask my app dev manager. We figured it out, I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured this out.
We had a serverside script in our default.aspx file writing the canonical links. That was causing the issue. As soon as it was removed the facebook sharer was working fine. Great blog module!